# Typescript undefined error produced for defined enum

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

In file defs.ts I define an enum and export it...

```tsx
enum MyState {
    state1 = 'state1'
    state2 = 'state2'
... state5 = 'state5'
}
```

this gets exported to `index.tsx` of a Component and exported from there

```tsx
export {
    MyState,
    ... 
}
```

It then gets imported into a file in another Component

```tsx
import { MyState } from "../Component1"

const filterMap: { [key: string]: { title: string; filter: object } } = {
  s1: { title: 's1', filter: { state: MyState.state1 } },
  s2: { title: 's2', filter: { state: MyState.state2 } },
  s2: { title: 's3', filter: { state_ne: [MyState.state3 ] } },
}
```

However on being run, an error gets generated

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MyState')`

WTF is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

**defs.ts**

```
export enum MyState {
    state1 = 'state1',
    state2 = 'state2',
    state5 = 'state5',
}
```

**Component2.tsx**

```
import { MyState } from './defs'
const filterMap: { [key: string]: { title: string; filter: object } } = {
  s1: { title: 's1', filter: { state: MyState.state1 } },
  s2: { title: 's2', filter: { state: MyState.state2 } },
  s2: { title: 's3', filter: { state_ne: [MyState.state5 ] } },
}
```

If you need to export it from an intermediary you would do something like this.

Component1.tsx

```
export * from './defs'
```

I

Comment: Yep it appears adding an intermediary layer upsets things - thanks